# Find the locus of the point which divides segment AB internally in the ratio 1:2.

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, locus

A and B are variable points on X and Y axis respectively,such that l(ab)=4.Find the locus of the point which divides segment AB internally in the ratio 1:2.

I think that it must be a circle . or another curve it cant be a straight line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: It is a ellipse. To see this suppose that you have $A=(x,0)$ and $B=(0,y)$, so:
$$
x^2+y^2=4
$$
Also there are tow points that divide the segment $AB$ internally by $1:2$ and these are $(s,t)=(\frac{x}{3},\frac{2y}{3})$ and $(z,w)=(\frac{2x}{3},\frac{y}{3})$. Now you can replace $x,y$ in the previous equation by $s,t,z,w$:
$$
x^2+y^2=9s^2+\frac{9t^2}{4}=4
$$ 
and
$$
x^2+y^2=\frac{9z^2}{4}+9w^2=4
$$ 
which are two ellipses.
[image]